# Connecting Google Analytics with Gooddata's Cloudconnect via an API

Tags: api, etl, gooddata

I have been given an ETL project as a task which requires me to ingest some data gleaned from GA into Gooddata via an API and perform some ETL operations. Also, the creation of reports and dashboards are an integral part of this assignment.

It is my first time using this platform. If there's any way, method or procedure that you can recommend me for doing this, that will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you are new to GoodData, the basic tutorial may help you understand basic concepts - https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/GoodData+Developer+Tutorial

Specifically for data loads, there are several ways how to load data into GoodData platform.

You can look at https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/Data+Loading as a starting point.

As you are specifically mentioning API, I recommend to this part of documentation - https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/Loading+Data+via+REST+API

In case you are interested for component ready for direct communication with GA, you can use "Google Analytics Reader" component https://help.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/gareader.html within CloudConnect Designer (https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/CloudConnect+Designer)

If you intend to transform data prior loading into GoodData platform, CloudConnect can be utilised or (depending on your GoodData environment) Agile Datawarehousing Service (https://help.gooddata.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=34341138) tied to Automated Data Distribution (https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/Automated+Data+Distribution) may be option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite general, but regarding GA and using CloudConnect I recommend you to check the example in GoodData documentation:

https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/CloudConnect+Example+Projects#CloudConnectExampleProjects-GoogleAnalyticsExampleProject